# AxisObject Bug?

Tags: graphics, bugs, ticks

**Bug introduced in 12.3 and persists in 13.0**

---

Is this a bug of AxisObjec? Or I have misunderstood the usage?

My understanding is that by setting the option `TickLabels` to  `TickLabels -> {All, All}` will give tick labels to both the major and minor ticks. However, currently it only gives labels to the major ticks.

```
Graphics[
 AxisObject[Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], {0, 10}, 
  TickPositions -> {{0, 10, 2}, {1, 9, 2}}, 
  TickLabels -> {All, All}]]
```

Comment: Re the tag [tag:bugs]: "This tag will be added to questions about problems that have subsequently been confirmed by other users to be caused by bugs in Mathematica. It should not be used when asking new questions. If you know that a certain behavior is a confirmed bug, please report it to [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) instead (or e-mail support@wolfram.com)."

Answer (score 11):

It looks like this is a bug to me. Based on david's comment and Michael's answer, we see:

```
TracePrint[
    ToBoxes @ Graphics[
        AxisObject[
            Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], 
            {0, 10}, 
            TickPositions -> {{0, 10, 2}, {1, 9, 2}}, 
            TickLabels -> {All, All}
        ]
    ],
    _System`Dump`formatTickLabelSet,
    TraceInternal -> True
]

            System`Dump`formatTickLabelSet[All,StandardForm]

            System`Dump`formatTickLabelSet[All,StandardForm]
```

> GraphicsBox[
> AxisBox[LineBox[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], {0, 10},
> TickLabels -> {Automatic, Automatic},
> TickPositions -> {{0, 10, 2}, {1, 9, 2}}]]

As Michael says, note that the [`TickLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TickLabels) option has been changed from `{All, All}` to `{Automatic, Automatic}`.

Now, the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) for `` System`Dump`formatTickLabelSet `` are:

```
Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = False},
    Print @ Column @ DownValues @ System`Dump`formatTickLabelSet
]
```

> HoldPattern[formatTickLabelSet[Automatic,fmt_]]:>Automatic
> HoldPattern[formatTickLabelSet[None|False,fmt_]]:>None
> HoldPattern[formatTickLabelSet[All|True,fmt_]]:>Automatic
> HoldPattern[formatTickLabelSet[ticklabels_List,fmt_]]:>(LabelToBoxes[#1,fmt,Automatic]&)/@ticklabels

Notice that [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/All) gets sent to [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic). This looks like a bug to me. One possibility is to do:

```
System`Dump`formatTickLabelSet[All, _] := All
```

Then:

```
ToBoxes @ Graphics[
    AxisObject[
        Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], 
        {0, 10}, 
        TickPositions -> {{0, 10, 2}, {1, 9, 2}}, 
        TickLabels -> {All, All}
    ]
]
```

> GraphicsBox[
> AxisBox[LineBox[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], {0, 10}, TickLabels -> {All, All},
> TickPositions -> {{0, 10, 2}, {1, 9, 2}}]]

And this renders correctly:

```
RawBoxes @ %
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

On my Mac, @kglr's fix shows an error that can be fixed by executing the menu command Cell > Show Expression twice after selecting the output cell.

Here is another way to fix the problem, which is that the `TickLabels` option as created by `MakeBoxes[]` is `TickLabels -> {Automatic, Automatic}` instead of `TickLabels -> {All, All}`:

```
Graphics[
 AxisObject[Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], {0, 10}, 
  TickPositions -> {{0, 10, 2}, {1, 9, 2}}, 
  TickLabels -> {All, All}]]
NotebookWrite[NextCell[],
 NotebookRead[NextCell[]] /. 
  HoldPattern[TickLabels -> _] :> TickLabels -> {All, All}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A work-around: use `TickLabels -> Full` (or `TickLabels -> {All, Full}`)

```
Graphics @ AxisObject[Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 10}}], {0, 10}, 
    TickPositions -> {{0, 10, 2}, {1, 9, 2}}, 
    TickLengths -> {.5, .3}, 
    TickLabelPositioning -> {"Base", "Tip"}, 
    TickLabels -> Full]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 22, 2021)"

Comment: This does not work on Version 13.0

Comment: @bakerryd123, It works  on version 13.0 on wolfram cloud.

Comment: This correctly displays the graphics, but with a red box and generates a `Message`, "The TickLabels->Dump`formatTickLabels[Full, StandardForm] specification does not correspond to the given TickPositions." However, when I click the graphic, then outside the graphic a couple of times, the red box disappears. Win 10 Home, version 13.0.

Comment: Has anyone experiencing this specific error reported this to Wolfram Support? If not, can you, please, do this? Thanks!

Comment: @CATrevillian I have already reported the bug to WR